# Doing something when a process finishes

Tags: process-management

Sometimes when I wanted to do something like:

```
long_running_command; second_command
```

I forget the `; second_command` part. If I don't want to interrupt and restart the `long_running_command` (sometimes it's not possible, other times it has run for a significant time before I discover my mistake and that work would be wasted), I typically do something like

```
ps aux | grep long_running_command 
while (kill -0 <pid found above>); do sleep 1; done; second_command
```

(in another terminal)
and while it works, it results in the following error:

```
kill: kill <pid> failed: no such process
```

Is there a way to avoid that error, or a better way to schedule `second_command` shortly after `long_running_command` finishes.

(I use `zsh` on Debian Jessie).

Comment: Just redirect `kill`'s standard error to the bit bucket:  `while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done; other_command`.

Comment: Wonder why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Given Debian (Linux), and assuming there's only one `long_running_command`:

```
while [ -d /proc/$(pgrep -f 'long_running_command') ]; do sleep 0.1; done;  second_command
```

Or, if you know the PID:

```
while [ -d /proc/PID-HERE ]; do sleep 0.1; done; second_command
```

If it's a common situation:

```
waitrun() {
  while [ -d /proc/$1 ]; do sleep 0.1; done;
  shift
  "$@"
}
waitrun PIDHERE second_command
```

Comment: Why would you want to execute `pgrep` in the loop again and again and again...?

Comment: Only if you hadn't saved the pid

Comment: "-d" is if file or directory exists, so it would return just "/proc/" if pgrep not found process and will be also true. Your code doesn't work.

```while [ -n "$(pgrep <executed command>)" ]; do sleep 0.1; done; <second command>```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the zsh shell's built-in `wait` command - it'll do the work for you.

```
% date; sleep 30s &
Tue Aug  8 22:24:07 EDT 2017
[1] 31875
% wait %1; date
[1]  + done       sleep 30s
Tue Aug  8 22:24:37 EDT 2017
```

You can also use a PID rather than the job-spec above.  So,:

```
% date; sleep 30s &
Tue Aug  8 22:26:04 EDT 2017
[1] 1821
% wait 1821; date
[1]  + done       sleep 30s
Tue Aug  8 22:26:34 EDT 2017
```

The semantics are the same on bash too.

Comment: This seems to only work for backgrounded processes in the same shell. In the question I actually said "(in another terminal)", and when I tried this in a nother terminal than my `long_running_command`, I get something like "wait: pid 4513 is not a child of this shell".

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the thing. If command not found the loop breaks and executes a second command.

`while [ -n "$(pgrep <executed command>)" ]; do sleep 0.1; done; <second command>`